# No route found for POST /email

Tags: ajax, symfony

Controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/email/{name}/{email}/{subject}/{message}", name="email")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function indexAction($name, $email, $subject, $message, Request $request){

        var_dump($name, $email, $subject, $message);
        die;
}
```

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#contact-form').submit(function(event) {
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'./email',
                    data:"/"+$('#name').val()+"/"+$('#email').val()+"/"+$('#subject').val()+"/"+$('#message').val(),
                    success:function(response){
                        alert(response)
                    }
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I am trying to submit ajax request to the controller. Unfortunately i get 404, and the following error: 
No route found for "POST /email" (from "http://localhost/Portfolio/web/app_dev.php/")

PS. The code in the controller is for debuging purposes

Comment: First of all run `app/console debug:router` to see if your route exist or not. If there are duplicated routers then the one on top always wins!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your controller to accept only POST request and so you don't need to pass your arguments in the path :

```
/**
 * @Route("/email, name="email")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */

public function indexAction(Request $request){

//your code here

}
```

To access your post parameters in the controller, use `$name = $request->request->get('name');` or consider using [Symfony Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

You also need to change your ajax call to send an object in `data`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#contact-form').submit(function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/email',
                data: {
                     name: $('#name').val(),
                     subject: $('#subject').val(),
                     email: $('#email').val(),
                     message: $('#message').val()
                },
                success:function(response){
                    alert(response)
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will properly send a POST request to `/email`

Answer (score 0):

the route `/email/{name}/{email}/{subject}/{message}` means that you need to send the Request to an URL like this

```
/email/testName/example@gmail.com/TestSUbject/Testmessage
```

if you need the `/email` route to work just change the `@Route` annotation to `/email`

and in controller

```
$request->request->get('email');
//retrieve other fields
...
```

..
to access the values of the POST request

Also you can also use Symfony Forms to take the Advantages they offer like validation , CSRF Protection , etc